# SwiftUI: Dynamic Animation Speed Adjustment

Tags: swiftui

I have a fan image that I want to spin faster and slower when clicking plus and minus buttons. There is a toggle button to turn on and off the fan. What I have here is a working example, but the fan adjusts to speed only if I turn off the toggle then back on. How do I make it adjust to speed while the animation is running?

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isOn = false
@State private var speed = 0.5
private var foreverAnimation = Animation.linear.repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        Image("fan")
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isOn ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(isOn ? foreverAnimation.speed(speed) : .default)
        
        Spacer()
        HStack{
            Button("+"){
                speed += 0.3
            }
            Button("-"){
                speed -= 0.3
            }
        }
        Spacer()
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn){
        }
        .labelsHidden()
        Text("\(speed)")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Following @vacawama reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75125597/9647237), this happens because your fan already has an animation, so you need to change your fan image and the animation each time your speed state value changes.

To accomplish what you want, your code should look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOn: Bool = false
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0.0
    @State private var speed: Double = 0.5
    @State private var fanID: UUID = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "fan")
                .id(fanID)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button("+") {
                    speed += 0.3
                }
                Button("-") {
                    speed -= 0.3
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {}
                .labelsHidden()
            Text("\(speed)")
            Spacer()
        }
        .onChange(of: speed) {
            rotationAngle = 0
            fanID = UUID()
            
            changeAnimation()
        }
        .onChange(of: isOn) {
            changeAnimation()
        }
    }
    
    private func changeAnimation() {
        withAnimation(Animation.linear.speed(speed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
            if isOn {
                rotationAngle = 360
            } else {
                rotationAngle = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```